# "Кстати(?) да..." — правомерно ли не ставить запятую?

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

> Кстати(?) да, ты права.

Правомерно ли будет не поставить запятую в данном предложении?
Кажется, запятая не ставится, так как выражение "кстати да" является цельным, но всё же закрадываются некоторые сомнения.

Answer (score 3):

Возможны два варианта:

(1) ***Кстати да, ты права.*** (2) ***Кстати, да, ты права.***

Выражение ***кстати () да***  встречается в Нацкорпусе, и чаще там ставится запятая, хотя есть варианты и без запятой.

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EA%F1%F2%E0%F2%E8%20%E4%E0&p=1

Например, к заданному вопросу подходит такая ситуация (запятой там нет):

*Кстати да,  когда растворяешься в любимом, это всегда плохо заканчивается.* [Женщина + мужчина: Психология любви (форум) (2004)]

Из словаря:

**ДА** 3. (при неожиданном воспоминании о чём-л. упущенном в предшествующем разговоре, при перемене темы разговора и т.п.). ***Кстати, вот ещё. Да, вот ещё что.***

*Кстати да* и *кстати, да* звучат по-разному. В первом случае ударение делается на "да" с его значением (вспомнил об упущенном), а во втором случае два ударения - кстати, вспомнил об упущенном. Поэтому  здесь две  формы написания, два значения и два разных произношения.

Comment: "Есть варианты и без запятой" — это Вы про цитаты из коллективных форумов? Там все что угодно найти можно.

Comment: Не в этом дело. Обратите внимание на то, что "кстати" и "да" дублируют друг друга. Автор вопроса считает это выражение цельным, так как пауза там отсутствует, и запятую ставить не собиралась. Вопрос спорный. Если слова имеют одинаковое значение, то может быть одно слово усиливает другое. Но и создавать "цельные выражения" мы тоже не можем, для этого нужно словарное подтверждение, а у нас его нет. Поэтому на форумах можно написать по слуху, но правилам это не будет соответствовать.

Comment: Возможно, где-то  "кстати" и "да" могут заменять друг друга. Например, герой вдруг вспомнил что-то: "Да, я забыл тебе сказать..." или "Кстати, я забыл тебе сказать..." Но в таком случае их не ставят рядом. Я во всех Ваших примерах у них разная роль.

Comment: Решила изменить ответ

Answer (score 2):

**Кстати, да, ты права.** Или даже так: **Кстати. Да, ты права** или  **Кстати! Да, ты права.**

Не вижу цельности. *Кстати* — вводное слово, *да* - частица.

> [ДА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x), частица. 1. Выражает согласие при ответе (противоп.: нет). Вы здесь? - Да. Меня звали? - Да. Мы где-то встречались? - Да, безусловно. Люблю ли я эту женщину? Да, и тысячу раз да. // Подтверждает ранее высказанное; действительно, совершенно, верно, конечно. В глазах теплилась надежда. Да, именно надежда. А мне понравилось. Да, понравилось.

О смысле этой фразы. Герой давно хотел сказать ей, что она права (это как бы ответ на невысказанный вопрос): "Да, ты права", — и вот подвернулся подходящий момент, можно добавить это к сказанному ранее, "кстати".

> [КСТАТИ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_379&layout=item), вводное слово
>   Указывает на смысловую связь между предшествующим и последующим высказываниями. То же, что «в дополнение к сказанному, в связи со сказанным выше».

Comment: А если читать, допустим, с акцентом на то, что это было сказано кстати к чему-то? "Кстати да, ты права!"-воскликнул он.

Comment: С акцентом на то, что это было сказано кстати? **Кстати! Да, ты права.** А "кстати, да" акцентирует *да*. Но все равно запятая нужна по правилам, хоть и нет паузы.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!