# Нужна ли запятая после "кстати"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Кстати неплохой. Очень неплохой!*

Answer (score 3):

***Нужна.*** От слово *неплохой* нельзя задать вопрос к слову *кстати.* Например, не спросишь *"каким образом неплохой?".* Поэтому это ***вводное слово*** и **запятая нужна**.

Однако стоит отметить, что есть выражение ***кстати да***, в котором запятая может не ставиться при произнесении без паузы с ударением на *да* (см. ответ Sharon на [этот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445850/%D0%9A%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E) вопрос).

Answer (score 2):

В качестве дополнения. 
Как уже показал Артём, в данном примере "кстати" работает как *вводное слово* (запятая нужна). Возможны случаи, когда это слово модифицирует глагол, причастие или деепричастие, действуя как *обстоятельство* образа действия (запятая не нужна):

> (Очень) *кстати подали* острый соус (*кстати пришедшийся* к мясу). Он слушал
>   собеседника, *кстати* и некстати *кивая*.

Answer (score 2):

***Кстати*** неплохой. Очень неплохой!

А мне кажется, что **можно обойтись без запятой** (***кстати*** тогда наречие, а не вводное слово), и вот почему.

1) ***Кстати*** может быть наречием? Да.

2) Наречие относится только к глаголам? Нет, **оно может относиться и к прилагательным тоже.**

3) **Пауза есть? Нет**, сочетание произносится в одну фразу.

4) **И почему тогда это вводное слово?**

Вводное слово обычно относится ко всей ситуации, а не к одному слову (см. примеры из словаря).

КСТАТИ II. вводн. сл. Употр. для обозначения того, что данная фраза говорится в связи с только что сказанным, **в дополнение к нему.** Мы скоро уезжаем, к., нельзя ли здесь заказать билеты? У нас в гостях был ваш племянник, к., он очень славный человек.

Comment: Вводное - по смыслу. Его можно рассматривать как сокращение от "кстати сказать". К тому же, затруднительно  составить какое-либо "невводное" сочетание с _прилагательным_.

Comment: А если так: Подали соус, кстати неплохой. Очень неплохой! (А в нашем случае - парцелляция).

Comment: То же самое: вводное слово (= кстати говоря). Расстановка пауз сама по себе не отменяет запятых.

Comment: Вы здесь поставите запятую? Вводное слово относится к обособленному обороту и запятой от него не отделяется.

Comment: Alex_ander, продолжим разговор? У Вас довольно-таки устойчивая позиция, можете "выиграть партию".

Comment: Поставил бы - для различения смысла "то, что он был неплохим, было кстати" и вводности; в пользу запятой есть ещё тень сокращаемого деепричастного оборота "кстати говоря".

Comment: Нет, мне кажется Вы не на верном пути. Различение смысла делается для однородных конструкций и сложных предложений, а к обособленному обороту вводное слово присоединяется всегда (еще со времен 1956 года). Что касается "кстати говоря", то этот оборот только по смыслу близок к вводному слову "кстати", а по грамматическим показателям он другой.  Он всегда обособляется, так как наречием быть не может, и к обособленному обороту его не присоединишь. У него структура другая и поэтому другие возможности.

Comment: Я бы изменил правило, постановляющее не ставить запятую внутри обособленного оборота, - оно приводит двусмысленности :) . Это видно и в примерах к приведённой здесь подборке правил: https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/kstati.html - можно двояко трактовать "кстати в мае (= самый подходящий месяц)" и "кстати забрали (= и правильно сделали!)". Кстати, у этих составителей все случаи хоть с одной запятой трактуются в пользу "вводности".

Answer (score 1):

Ответ второй (после обсуждения)

***Кстати неплохОй.*** Очень неплохой!

*Для сравнения: **Кстати говоря**, неплохой, очень неплохой!*

Конечно, в большинстве случаев ***кстати*** обособляется в качестве вводного слова со значением "кстати говоря", реже оно не обособляется в качестве **наречия** со значениями "вовремя или заодно", но при этом наречие относится к глаголу.

Но вот в этом случае не хочется обособлять ***кстати***: паузы нет, ударение падает на прилагательное. Слово ***кстати*** явно относится к этому прилагательному и произносится с ним в одну фразу.

С одной стороны, наречие **может относиться к прилагательному**, но вот значение у  ***кстати***  для наречия неподходящее, на что мне и было указано.

Да, верно, здесь есть о чем подумать... Но есть еще вариант: **вводное слово умеет присоединяться к обособленному обороту,** тогда оно не отделяется от него.

Здесь нет обособленного оборота? Но зато здесь присутствует **явная парцелляция,** то есть это только часть фразы, например: *Подали соус, **кстати неплохой**. Очень неплохой!*

Пример

А на барабанах играл Зак Старки, сын Ринго Старра, **и кстати неплохой ударник** (но все же не папа, и уж совсем не Кит Мун). [Александр Журбин. Как это делалось в Америке. Автобиографические заметки (1999)]

Comment: *Но вот в этом случае не хочется обособлять кстати: паузы нет, ударение падает на прилагательное.* По такой же логике (нет паузы, ударения) и мне не хотелось отделять вводное "может" в примерах, подобных такому: *Может(,) и ты с нами пойдёшь?" Но все хором говорят, что запятая нужна.

Comment: Ну вот! А я надеялся, вы как-то прокомментируете.

Comment: Артем, так вспомнить же надо, подумать надо.  Я всегда стараюсь по возможности вам ответить в первую очередь. Тут такое дело. 1) Не стоит думать, что мы всегда можем выделить вводное слово интонацией (паузой, ударением), и чем сложнее структура, тем меньше для этого возможностей. В вашем примере вводное   слово  входит в первую часть предложения: Может, и тЫ с нами//пойдЁшь? Это двухчастная конструкция, на три части ее не разделишь. Поэтому действует чисто грамматический принцип постановки запятой: паузы нет, а запятая есть.

Comment: 2) "Кстати неплохой". Здесь ДРУГОЕ ДЕЛО. В предложении всего два слова, поэтому на интонацию следует ориентироваться.  Мы явно произносим это без обозначенной паузы. А в своем ответе я объясняю, почему наречие "кстати" может относиться к прилагательному. Запятая не ставится ни по грамматике, ни по интонации.

Comment: Спасибо! Только я никак не соглашусь, что "кстати" тут может быть наречием.

Comment: Ну не наречие, так слово, которое в данном случае выступает в функции присоединительного союза.  Запятой и паузы там нет, а если нет, то это не вводное слово. А что тогда? Как Вы его назовете? Надо же слово отнести хотя бы  к какой-то части речи. Вводное слово самостоятельной частью речи обычно не считают, так как нет у вводных слов общей морфологии. Это особый класс слов, но эти слова проявляют себя только на уровне синтаксиса.

Comment: Не знаю даже, как назвать... Но понял Вашу мысль.

Comment: Мысль совсем простая. Вот предложение: "Неплохой кстати". Слово "кстати" - это какая часть речи? Вы не хотите назвать это слово наречием,  потому что оно не выполняет функцию наречия в этом предложении, но тогда что это? Какие-нибудь морфологические признаки у него есть, если рассматривать его отдельно от предложения?

Comment: Артем, у меня появилась идея назвать слово  "кстати" частицей. В роли наречия оно выступает только по отношению к глаголу (сказать что-то кстати). В остальных случаях это  вводное слово, которое относится ко всему предложению, но не всегда. Иногда оно умеет "клеиться" к отдельным словам, не отделяется от них паузой, но при этом сохраняет значение вводности (=кстати говоря). Так могут вести себя только частицы. Как вам нравится эта идея?

Comment: По-моему, отличная идея! Наверное, вы правы. ;)

Comment: Артем, вы для меня как эталон ясности. Если вы что-то не понимаете, то здесь две причины: 1) я это тоже не понимаю, хотя думаю, что понимаю; 2) я это объясняю недостаточно понятно.

Comment: Ну прямо совсем захвалили!)))

Comment: Я всегда говорю только правду. Практически...